# Building project on ionic cordova android fails with UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

When I build my project with ionic cordova on android platform, I receive the following error and it does not build the apk.  It does not reference any particular file like it normally does where there are errors, so I'm not sure how to start debugging this particular problem.  I don't have the word "variables" anywhere in my own src, so this is coming from somewhere else.

> (node:16780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
>   (node:16780) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I see that it references node:16780, which I think is a line number of "something".  What file would that be?

Anything thing else I can do to debug this?

I'm using ionic 4.0.2 with cordova-android 7.1.1, building on my own Windows computer.

The exact same code builds properly on cordova-android 6.4.0 with the online phonegap-build, but pgb does not yet offer 7.1.1.

Comment: It looks like the answer is there: "DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code." You have a promise somewhere you haven't defined a handler for promise rejection.

Comment: The problem is that it is "somewhere".  Generally, an error will say something like somefile.ts at line 100, not "somewhere" within your entire project.

Comment: Also, it's not just a warning, it actually stops the build or run process.  Even though it says warning, it does not allow the program to continue building.